# PHP image resize not working

Tags: php, jpeg, image-resizing

I'm trying to create a thumbnail from a JPG image, but I can't get the resized image to output properly ("contains errors").

Here's my code, I can't figure out what's wrong:

```
<?php   
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$photos = glob($_GET['a'] . '/*.*');
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($photos[array_rand($photos)]);

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img);
if($width > $height) {
    $newWidth = 250;
    $newHeight = 250*$height/$width;
}
else {
    $newHeight = 250;
    $newWidth = 250*$width/$height;
}

$tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($tmp, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

// Output the image
imagejpeg($tmp);
?>
```

Comment: possibly you have to install gd extension, apt-get install php7.0-gd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) requires a filename, not an image resource. It emits a warning, that's why the image was not valid, because there is a string before the image binary.

```
$photos = glob($_GET['a'] . '/*.*');
$filename = $photos[array_rand($photos)] ;
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
```

or use [`imagesx()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagesx.php) and [`imagesy()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagesy.php) to get image size using `$img`.

```
$photos = glob($_GET['a'] . '/*.*');
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($photos[array_rand($photos)]);
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem!

Comment: @bur Don't forget to remove/comment temporarily the `header()`, the next time, to see the errors, before the binary content :)

Comment: Yeah, I will remember next time, should have been my first response ^^ Thanks!